Spawn unique instance per point
I'm trying to instance a collection of images, such that each point has a unique image.
When using a mesh to points node to create the points, everything works fine when set to Vertices, Corners, or Edges. However, when setting it to Face mode, it will only spawn the same image on every point.
Correct Behavior when set to vertices mode:

Incorrect Behavior when set to face mode:

Current Node Setup:

Is there some sort of separation that needs to happen with the points so they are unique index values?
File Included:


please do not ask more than one question. Mabey read again: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. You can open as many questions as you like - so just copy it and open new questions. thx for your understanding.

It was not meant to be a multipart question. It is meant to be singular, with the additional information to provide context on where i’m headed so that if it turns out that it would be a waste of time to set it up one way because I would then need to redo it all if that basic idea can’t work with the overall idea. That’s why I didn’t ask how to do those things, merely mentioned my future goal. I will try to phrase that more clearly next time but was aiming for brevity.

If you take a closer look, you would have seen that this isn't a bug. You have checked "picked instances". So Blender does this, because you didn't plug in any instance index there. And it seems to take the index of the source element (which is a cube's face/vertex/edge). Because you deleted every face except one, the index is always 0.
You can check this out if you just mute your delete geometry node, because then you will see more than one image.
You can use the realize instances node before the delete geometry node to get different instances picked by Blender.

How do I get from that knowledge to getting this to function? If the index of each face is 0 on each cube, then what would I do in order to renumber the values of each face? There are 3 faces left because there are 3 boxes that have their other faces deleted. How can I get each of those faces to be considered part of a new grouping of index values?

just put a realize instances node before the delete geometry

Thank you! That was what I needed. I see why I was so confused now. When I have "Separate Children" checked on the collection info (which I did in my original file, before creating a duplicate to ask this question). It shows the instances in the viewer: https://imgur.com/ehdKHba
However, the images are all the same per point. I don't understand why instance index values don't work as a possible solution to the same problem. Does the spreadsheet info indicate this? I feel like there's a fundamental idea at the core here that I'm missing.
